# Google Sheets: extract one column of a named range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

### update

My original question was about taking the average of a single column of a named range.  But upon reflection, the question generalizes to "how do I extract a single column from a named range?"

### original question

I'm using a named range to extract two columns from a large dataset.  Assume `MyRange` defines three rows and two columns out of a larger dataset:

```
 ... |G   |H   | ...
+----|----|----|
| ...          |
|2000|15.1|  10|
|2001|15.2|  23|
|2002|15.3|  30|
| ...          |
```

Using `MyRange`, how would I take the average of (only) column `H`?
I've tried various things like `AVERAGE(MyRange:H)`, and `AVERAGE(INDEX(MyRange 1))` but haven't figured out the proper syntax.
*(In the above example, the result should be 21.)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or there's the tried and trusted way with index:

```
=average(index(NamedRange1,0,2))
```

(specifying 0 for the row means use the entire column)

Comment: Ah!  That's what I was looking for.  I didn't know about the significance of a 0 in the row field.

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled upon a simpler approach using `FILTER()`:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(MyRange, {FALSE, TRUE}))
```

It works because `FILTER(MyRange, {FALSE, TRUE})` extracts (only) the second column, which is in turn passed to `AVERAGE()`.

Comment: Interesting solution :)

Comment: love this solution for filtering out columns, works great for virtual ranges

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query:

```
=Query(ArrayFormula(MyRange), "select avg(H) label avg(H) ''")
```

---

*As an alternative.*

Why not just **create a new named range** from the 3 rows in column `H`e.g. `MyRangeH`?
Then, use:

```
=AVERAGE(MyRangeH)
```

Comment: I'm using named ranges with two columns because I need the first column for other calculations -- they are logically tied together.  If I created a separate named range, they could get out of sync.

Comment: I see. You could use the query then. But I have to admit. I like your solution more.

Answer (score 2):

Following the now updated question:

> My original question was about taking the average of a single column of a named range. But upon reflection, the question generalizes to "how do I extract a single column from a named range?"

One could also use:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(MyRange,0,2))
```

About **[`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)**